# Javascript: rounded parentheses surrounding comma separated expressions

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Playing on JS console I faced a curious syntax. I wonder if someone can tell me more on that..

Try this:

```
>( function f(){console.log('i am f')} , (function x(){console.log('i am x')})() , y=2 , console.log('hello') )
i am x
hello
undefined
>f()
ReferenceError: f is not defined
>this.y
2
```

This will fail:

> ( var c=2 )
>       SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

So comma separated expressions inside parentheses are evaluated, assignments happens to be against global scope, but named function declarations references stay trapped inside just like a closure
more...
putting that line inside a function declaration called with *new*:

```
function C(){
    ( function f(){console.log('i am f')} , (function x(){console.log('i am x')})() , y=2 , console.log('hello') )
}
```

and then instantiating:

```
>var c=new C()
i am x
hello
undefined
>c.y
undefined
>this.y
2
```

Happens exactly the same, just as executed in the global scope!

What's the usage / purpose of this construct?

One more:

```
>( function f(){console.log('i am f')} , f() )
ReferenceError: f is not defined
```

So the named function can't be referenced neither inside brackets.

Comment: The named functions aren't "trapped inside", because they're not _function declarations_ (using `function` as a statement), they are in fact _function expressions_ (using `function` as an operator).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The named functions aren't "trapped inside", because they're not *function declarations* (using [`function` as a statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)), they are in fact *function expressions* (using [`function` as an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)). This means that their names do not become references to themselves in the current namespace.

---

Certain keyword/tokens can only be used as statements, such as `var`, hence an error is thrown if you try to use them in conditions which the interpreter expects to be an expression.

---

As for the `y === 2`, this is because you did not `var y;` inside `C`, so `y = 2` sets `window.y`, and in the global scope `this === window`.

---

> whats the usage / purpose of this construct?

- The [comma operator `,`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) lets you do multiple expressions on one line.
- *function expressions* are useful for a great many things, be it immediately invoking them so you have a closure, or storing them inside variables, etc.

Comment: Also: the name of a named function expression is supposed to be visible only inside the function itself (to allow recursion), hence the error that f is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping code in parentheses forces it to be parsed as an expression.

The `var` keyword is only valid as a statement, so this creates a syntax error.

Function declarations can either be statements (which create a hoisted variable) or expressions (which do not create any variable).

Thus, wrapping the function in parentheses turns it into a function expression, which does not create an externally-visible name.

For more information, see [here](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/).

Comment: very good article!
ok about declaration vs expression..
what about assignment to global object, even when evaluated inside "another this"
use cases (apart of self exec functions for isolated closure)?

Comment: @aleclofabbro: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: i mean that (x=1,y=2) always implicitily assign x and y to the globalobject ( globalobject.x == 1 and globalobject.y == 2 ) even if it is evaluated inside a constructor function

Comment: @aleclofabbro: That's because you didn't declare them as local variables.  Note that global scope is not the same as `this`.